# jQuery 'on' event, check if NOT ON

Tags: php, jquery

I have a running event checking if I am hovering a link after something that been `POSTED`, using the on event.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#hover",function() {
    load(); 

    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("#sidebar").html('');

    $.post("ajax_search.php?type=sidebar", { sidebar : $("#search").val() }, function(get_data) {
        stop_load();

        $("#sidebar").html(get_data);
    });
});
```

**Question**

How do I make it so when you stop hovering `#hover`, `#sidebar` will hide?
I am posting the `#hover`, that's why I use the `ON` event.

Is there an even like `notOn`?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery's `mouseout` or `mouseleave` events may be helpful. http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: First and foremost, **`.on()` is not an event**. `.on()` is a jQuery method that allows standardized attachment of event handlers. In the code above, 'mouseenter' is the event.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no `notOn`.

But there's a counterpart for `mouseenter`: `mouseleave`.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#hover",function() {
    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Stupid me, you're absolutely right. Thanks! didn't know there is mouseleave ^^.

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for it's a [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event which allows you to use two event handlers one mouse enter and other when mouse leave,

Another way to accomplish it's something like

```
$(".selector").on(
{
mouseenter: function() 
{
    //stuff to do on mouseover
},
mouseleave: function()
{
    //stuff to do on mouseleave
}
});
```

Comment: I may not be right, but i think he is using .on() because he is adding the element dynamically, and hover play's up a lot with dynamically added content. (May be Wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mouseleave event:

```
$(document).on("mouseleave","#hover",function() {
      //Code required to hide the sidebar.
 });
```

You might also want to consider lazily executing your ajax call, caching the result, and ensuring that it is only loaded once.

Also, don't rely on methods which Toggle. I would explicitly use fadeIn and fadeOut on mouseenter and mouseleave, just in case the order in which events are resolved ever gets lagged.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `notOn` method. But in the following example the `mouseout` function will behave as the `notOn` you're looking for. Here's an example:

```
$('#hover').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // perform operations when you're hovering on #hover element
        $('#sidebar').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseout: function(){
        // perform operations when you stop hovering over #hover element    
        $('#sidebar').fadeOut();    
    }
});
```